# Did Queensland Greens candidate Jonathan Sriranganathan teach people how to break into buildings?

Tags: politics, australia, advertising

The Queensland local elections are next week.

I've seen an attack ad via text message against the Greens candidate for Lord Mayor of Brisbane, [Jonathan Sriranganathan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Sriranganathan). It claims he held a class teaching people how to case buildings for breaking into them, concluding with a short video of him saying that it's safer for everyone if criminals break into abandoned buildings.

Today, I received this text message:

> The Greens’ Lord Mayoral Candidate Jonathan Sriranganathan published a guide to help people scope out properties to break into.
>
> Watch the video above to see it first-hand.
>
> Your local Greens candidate, Michaela Sargent, backs Jonathan Sriranganathan's radical agenda.
>
> Crime is a serious issue in Brisbane.
>
> We can’t risk The Greens making Brisbane less safe and using City Hall as a platform to push their extreme views.
>
> Auth: B Riley, 281 Sandgate Rd, Albion 4010

This [Linked In post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/damian-brander-b718475b_the-greens-lord-mayoral-candidate-jonathan-activity-7172475086304653312-cmUg) has the same text and includes the video.

(Note to non-Australians: The last line "Auth" is due to [Australian electoral laws](https://www.aec.gov.au/about_aec/authorisation.htm) requiring campaign materials to be attributable.)

Did Sriranganathan teach a class into breaking into buildings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nine News Queensland's Facebook page has [this August 2022 video](https://www.facebook.com/9NewsQueensland/videos/greens-councillor-encourages-squatters-in-brisbane/742683567034941/) video, *Greens councillor encourages squatters in Brisbane*.

It includes a shot of a Facebook post: [image: Facebook post discussing unoccupied dwelling statistics]

[That 17 August 2022 post](https://m.facebook.com/jonno.sri/posts/605511920944392/?_se_imp=0sY8EmAsQiFSgnGbX) is on Sriranganathan's Facebook page still.

An [August 2022 Daily Mail article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-11122143/Brisbane-mayor-Adrian-Schrinner-hits-Greens-Jonathan-Sriranganathan-squatting-advice.html)  has screenshots of comments by Johnathan I haven't been able to independently verify are in that Facebook post that appear to be the source of the "leave some tape around the edge of the front door" quote that shows up in places:
[image: Johnathan discussing ways to verify if someone lives in a place]

Assuming this is the thing the LNP ad is about, Johnathan has discussed how to determine if a property is lived in or not in the context of squatting in abandoned buildings. He claims there are a lot of abandoned investment properties around Brisbane and that it would be better if homeless people squatted in them instead. See [this Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/jonno.sri/posts/a-couple-of-journalists-and-conservative-commentators-are-working-themselves-int/606112244217693/), and [this Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/jonno.sri/posts/pfbid0PTSU1QqyrvaSEk7NoJqC9DwpRG5BXmDK69vXkKArdauLCtcb3kURJtGaaYa4igYal) published in the days afterwards, for examples..

It does seem fair to me to say that Johnathan "published a guide to help people scope out properties to break into." about that Facebook comment, although it is perhaps a little overblown. It is up to you to determine whether the context is important: it's about squatting in long-term vacant properties if you would otherwise be homeless.